# Vector c++ no match for operator* when multiplying two elements of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, operators, stdvector

This is a part of a code I wrote:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) a.push_back(i);
while(a.size()!=1){
    b+=a.begin()*a.end()+a.begin()+a.end();
    a.erase(a.begin());
    a.erase(a.end());
    }
```

This is the first time I am using vectors, so I dont know where I went wrong.
The error I get is:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’ and ‘std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’)
       b+=a.begin()*a.end()+a.begin()+a.end();
          ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `begin` returns an iterator which behaves like a pointer. Can you multiply pointers?

Comment: To get the value from iterator use *itr

Comment: @MarekR Probably, he wants to `b += <first_element>*<last_element>+<first_element>+<last_element>`

Comment: Is that while loop inside for loop and you're missing a bracket? If not, should remove indentation so that we can understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are ususing `std::vector` here? Could you show more code? The use of `std::vector` might be overkill here or even kill performance depending on how your code is used.

Answer (score 2):

`begin()` and `end()` return *iterators*. You can't multiply iterators. Use `front()` and `back()` to access the first and last value.

```
b += a.front() * a.back() + a.front() + a.back();
```

Comment: I think that this code not very secure because if your vector is empty your application crashes. 
you must test if the iterators returned are valid

Comment: `*a.end()` undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks, totally missed that and feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you over complicating this code. You do not need vector to calculate this value.

```cpp
int f(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= (n + 1)/2; i++) {
        auto b = i;
        auto e = n + 1 - i;
        r += b * e + b + e;
    }
    return r;
}
```